# Google Account Information with oauth

Tags: php, google-app-engine, oauth

I am develop a application that allow login from other applications, eg.  Google, Facebook, linkedin, etc.
My question is, howto obtain the user account information from google, after login with oauth.
With user account information, i mean: name, email, date of birth, etc.

Thanks.

Comment: Login with OAuth? Do you mean OpenID?

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking about Google Apps, there's a lot of info on the APIs on Google Code: http://code.google.com/googleapps/docs/#auth

If you're just using Open ID with Google Accounts, I believe you can only get name + email address. There's some info (including code samples) in the Google Apps Marketplace docs: http://code.google.com/googleapps/marketplace/tutorial_php.html#Integrate-OpenID